# Is it required to notify a user and/or provide an opt-out when using location services?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I'm reading the Phone's location in one of my applications, and I don't know if I must ask user the question "This app uses your location, do you want run it?" before he run my application the first time? I heard about that apps without it can't be certified on Marketplace.  must add it or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per se, it is not required that you let the user know that location is used - there are application that passed certification with this. From an ethical standpoint, it might be a different question. When your application is downloaded, the user is alerted about the fact that it is using location services.

The certification requirements on this [state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184838%28v=vs.92%29):

> **6.1 - Location Aware Application**
>
> Users have the ability to turn off the Location Service on the phone from the System Settings page.
>   Location aware applications must remain responsive when the Location
>   Service is turned off on the phone.
>
> Recommendations:
>
> - Present a user-friendly message to indicate that location data is not available.

In addition, [however](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841%28v=vs.92%29):

> **2.7.2**
>
> The privacy policy of your application must inform users about how
>   location data from the Location Service API is used and disclosed and
>   the controls that users have over the use and sharing of location
>   data. This can be hosted within or directly linked from the
>   application.
>
> **2.7.3**
>
> Your application must provide in-application settings that allow the
>   user to enable and disable your application's access to and use of
>   location from the Location Service API.
>
> **2.7.4**
>
> If your application publishes or makes available location data
>   obtained from the Location Service API to any other service or other
>   person (including advertising networks), your application must
>   implement a method to obtain opt-in consent. To "implement a method to
>   obtain 'opt-in' consent," the application must:
>
> ```
> (a) first describe how the location information will be used or shared;
>
> (b) obtain the user's express permission before publishing the location information as described; and
>
> (c) provide a mechanism through which the user can later opt out of having the location information published. Your application must
> ```
>
> periodically remind users or provide a visual indicator that location
>   data is being sent to any other service or person.

Bottom line - additional notification is required if you **plan on publishing or storing the location**.

Comment: So it isn't required :) Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer to include additional details.

Comment: It's required, and you'll be informed so when submitting your app. Dennis should consider answer from experience if he had any, not vague guidelines.

Comment: Read the guidelines again. Additional notification is required only if the app is storing or publishing the location data.

Comment: The certification team don't know the difference, so they require it if you use the capability in the first place. If you actually made any apps, you would know :p

Comment: Check other location-aware apps and you will see exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: Yes, you'll notice they inform you of the usage. I happen to have made several apps using the GPS for various purposes, without storing it, and know exactly what our marketplace team asks for in the process.

Comment: Wouldn't be too sure about that. You've got Rowi, that notifies about the location services on download, but a) doesn't notify in-app about location usage b) doesn't have a location switch in-app

Comment: Link for details: http://www.withinwindows.com/2012/04/13/the-rowi-location-api-access-argument/

Answer (score 1):

> if I must ask user question "This app use your location, if you want run it?" before he run my application on first time? I heard about that apps without it can't be certified on Marketplace.

You must ask the user explicit the first time he/she uses the app. Simple as that. The capabilities that you approve when downloading it form the marketplace, is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact answer, but: I hope so. I don't want apps tracking my location without my explicit permission. Even if it's not required, do it anyway. Assuming it's not something inherently location-aware like Foursquare, when someone inevitably notices the tracking, your app will be all over the news (and not in a good way).

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes I have the same opinion but, when you installing app which use Location, before it you must accept it have access to your location. And I think that is asking user twice about one thing. But on some tutorials I heard that the apps without it cannot be confirm in Marketplace. So I ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

you are required to specify app capabilities in the Application Manifest Designer.

> A Metro style app runs in a security container with limited access to the file system, network resources, and hardware. Whenever a user installs an app from the Windows Store, Windows looks at the metadata in the Package.appxmanifest file to figure out what capabilities the app needs to function. For example, an app might need to access data from the Internet, documents from the user's Document Library, or the user's webcam and microphone. When the app is installed, it displays to the user the capabilities it needs, and the user must grant permission for it to access those resources. If the app doesn't request and receive access to a resource it needs, it will not be allowed access to that resource when the user runs it.

therefore it is done for you automatically. [see here for app capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx)

and yes the certification required that if user disable the app capability, your app must still remain responsive and indicate to the user that the capability is disable and advice the user on it.

Answer (score 0):

My app failed certification when I did not offer the user to turn Location Services on and off. I found the code in the link below to be an excellent workaround and it got my app certified.

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/02/wp7-sample-use-location-services-and.html